# Asp.net - Microsoft SQL Server outgoing connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I was wondering if there is a way to see if a server blocks outgoing connections. I am trying to connect to an external database from a client's server.

This is the error I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Edit:
I forgot to say I only have access to the plesk control panel. That's why I was asking if there is a way with asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "server", do you mean the asp.net server, or the SQL server?  And are both machines on the same network?  Is this hosted?

Sql Server:

- They can remove the OPENROWSET functionality, so you can't connect to remote servers, regardless
- I doubt they are giving you access to linked servers in a hosted env

ASP.Net

- You can try to connect to the other server via a regular connection, and see if that works.
- Download a [tracert component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/tracert.aspx), and use that to try to trace from your server to the remote one.

  - If it dies somewhere inside your network, then that is your answer (it is blocked)
  - If it works, the outbound is open.  Doesn't mean 1433 is open though.
  - If it dies after, not blocked, but maybe the remote is blocking icmp echo
  - Remember to try to tracert to somewhere else that you know works

It will be hard to tell what is killing the connection on 1433, if you can get to the server using other means.  Could be the firewall, their fw, etc.

Comment: No both machines are on different networks. I tried with 2 different database servers.

I'll give that tracert component a try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The trusty telnet method:

```
telnet theserver 1433
```

If this times out, the server is not listening.  If the screen blanks and you can type something, the server is listening and no firewall is blocking the connection.

In Vista and Windows 7, you have to install telnet as a Windows component from Control Panel -> Programs and Features.

Comment: I would like to add that if it times out, it means the client is unable to find a listening server corresponding to the supplied alias.  Does the alias map to the correct IP address when you ping it?  Is the IP address correct?

Comment: Ah, I don't have access to windows it self I only have the plesk login or is there a way to telnet from asp.net?

I'll update my question also.

Comment: Ping may also not be working.   So many ugly things block echo, so ping & tracert don't work.   It's probably better to try tracert and then ask the network admin if it doesn't work.  

From the message, i'm betting the connection is not allowed (firewall) or the remote server is set to only listen locally.

Comment: From my local machine my asp.net pages have access to the remote database.

Comment: If all you have is plesk the it sounds hosted.  I doubt that they have opened the firewall for 1433, what with the security issues.

Are both servers behind the same FW?

Comment: Nope the database server isn't on the same network. I tried to different database servers and both failed.